# Checkbox Checks All The Tasks Instead of The Relevant One Only

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

```
  taskContainer(String taskName, String taskPriority, String taskDetails) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colours().containerColour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colours().buttonShadow,
              blurRadius: 5,
              offset: const Offset(0, 5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: taskPriority == 'High'
                        ? Colours().highPriority
                        : taskPriority == 'Medium'
                            ? Colours().mediumPriority
                            : Colours().lowPriority,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                //check box
                Checkbox(
                  value: isSelectedList,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        isSelectedList = value!;
                        print('task status: $isSelectedList');
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  activeColor: Colours().checkedColour,
                  checkColor: Colours().primary,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        taskName,
                        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: isSelectedList
                              ? Colours().checkedColour
                              : Colours().unSelectedText,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Text(
                        '$taskPriority Priority',
                        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: isSelectedList
                              ? Colours().checkedColour
                              : Colours().unSelectedText,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                //SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
              ],
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                isSelectedList
                    ? deleteTask(
                        taskName,
                        taskPriority,
                        taskDetails,
                      )
                    : showTaskDetails(
                        taskName,
                        taskPriority,
                        taskDetails,
                      );
              },
              icon: isSelectedList
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      size: 35,
                    )
                  : Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is a code snippet of a task tracker application. The relevant parameters are passed on to this method from a ListView.builder, which is in the main UI widjet tree. It retrieves the tasks from firestore and then passes the relevant details to create the task card. It creates the task cards correctly.

Problem is, when user clicks a checkbox it marks all the check boxes in all the tasks, not that relevant one only. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Your (outer) state should contain a list of booleans to indicate whether they are selected, not a single boolean for the whole list.

Then, you can pass a boolean `isSelected` to each tile, which is the boolean at the current index of the `List<bool> isSelectedList`, and set the value at this index when the item is selected.

Comment: When I implement the list the following error occured

****Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)****

in the line,

Comment: Make sure you initialize the list with values corresponding to each tile. So if you have 3 tiles, it should start like `[false, false, false]`. If you `print` the index (or use a break point and the debugger) you can look which index it's trying to check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same variable **isSelectedList** to check the state of all checkbox, once you click on any checkbox that value will change for all tasks.

You can create a list of bool for all your tasks

```
List isSelectedList;
```

In your method you can pass the index of the task

```
taskContainer(String taskName, String taskPriority, String taskDetails, int index) {
    ...
}
```

Then to change or check the value, use that array and that index

```
Checkbox(
    value: isSelectedList[index],
    onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
            isSelectedList[index] = value!;
            print('task $index status: ${isSelectedList[index]}');
        },
        );
    },
    activeColor: Colours().checkedColour,
    checkColor: Colours().primary,
)
```

Comment: I done what you said, and got the folllowing error

****   Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)  ****

in the line, 

 value: isSelectedList[index],

Comment: You have to initialize the table depending on the number of elements you have,